# Sidekiq processing in after_create fetches wrong number of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, sidekiq

For some reason, Sidekiq gives me back 0 records for a query, after being triggered in an `after_create`.
However, if `process` would have `sleep 1` in it, it ALWAYS gives me the correct value (1 record).
What the hell is going on here?

**Model:**

```
after_create :after_create

def after_create
    AwardsWorker.perform_async(user_id)
end
```

**Worker:**

```
def perform(user_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  AwardEngine.added_shows_awards(user)
end
```

**AwardEngine:**

```
def self.added_shows_awards(user)
  count = user.followings(true).count #(true) to avoid AR caching
  puts "count: #{count}" #this is mostly 0! even if the database has 1 record
end
```

Comment: Try changing the after_create to after_commit. Perhaps it's something as "simple" as the transaction is not completed for the create process/call and Sidekiq runs its query before the create is committed to the DB. Just a thought for a quick test (or change the Sidekiq worker's call to AwardsWorker.delay_for(2.seconds)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use after_commit, as explained in the wiki:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345